# fa.random error: You have more than 8 categories for your items, polychoric is probably not needed

Tags: r, psych

I am trying to run the `fa.random` function on some big five data and am receiving the error:

> Error in polychoric(r, correct = correct, weight = weight) :
> You have more than 8 categories for your items, polychoric is probably not needed

Here is the code I am running:

```
fa.random(randomtest2, nfactor=3, cor="poly", fm="wls", rotate = "Promax")
```

All of my variables are numeric variables between 1 and 5 (five categories for my items, not more than 8).

I have tried converting the data to integer and factor data and have had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that error before, and it doesn't always seem to make ~logical~ sense! Have you tried running the correlation first and then trying the factor analysis?
R <-  polychoric(data=mydata,
use="complete.obs",ncat =8)

With the polychoric (also from Psych package), you can specify again that ncat = 8 which is the maximum number of response options before it considers a variable continuous.

Another thought is that your data is not structured correctly for the function to read it as it's programmed to. Good luck!